# Why VLOOKUP () doesn't work in this example in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, vlookup, right-to-left

This is a simple working example:
A column has these names:

`اسم عربي واحد` in A2

`اسم اجنبي اثنان` in A3

`اسم ثالث ثلاثة` in A4

`اسم رابع` in A5

The second column B2 has these numbers in front of the above names:

`61.2` in B2

`69.8` in B3

`73.7` in B4

`88.8` in B5

Now if I use `VLOOKUP()` it returns `TRUE` but not the matching number.

let's say I put in C column different names from above, I want to return the numbers using vlookup in column D:
so D2 has this formula:

`=VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$B$4,2,0)`

MWE:

[image]

How to retrieve the content instead of `true` in this example? Your help would be much appreciated.

LibreOffice:

Version: 5.1.3.2

Build ID: 1:5.1.3-0ubuntu1

CPU Threads: 4; OS Version: Linux 4.4; UI Render: default;

Locale: en-GB (en_US.UTF-8)

Comment: I did a quick little test and I'm not getting the same problem as you are.  All is working as expected and vlookup returns the correctly looked up number.  Your description is a little confusing.  You state "A2 cell in A column has these names", when I think you mean "column A has these names"; i.e. A2 just has the first "arabic one" name.  Similar correction for your B column, but also the numbers don't match your screen-shot.  Given the inconsistencies in description and examples, could you point us to a real example file that displays this incorrect behaviour.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` does not return a Boolean: it returns a value from the selected column, so it must be formatted the same. In your case column `B` is being returned, so column `D` should be formatted the same, ie numeric. (Your cell `C2` is obscured, so we cannot see the search value.)

Comment: @jehad, sorry for the confusing parts. But it works fine now. I don't know if I must delete the whole post by now if that is necessary.

Comment: @doctorate, that's fine.  Was there something useful you learned in using LibreOffice to fix your problem, which may help others avoid similar problems?  If not, and it was just bad data, you can delete the post.  Look for a "delete" option under your post.